# Unable to install Scrapy (Shell) in Ubuntu virtual machine on a Win system

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, vagrant, scrapy-shell

I am new on VM, but is following the book - Learning Scrapy by DKL. It seems to be setting up a Virtual environment via Vagrant and VirtualBox. I think I have everything set up - installed Vagrant and VirtualBox of ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Then I use Cmder.exe (in my project folder e:...\Project) to access Vagrant

```
λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

λ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
New release '14.04.5 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

This Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system is past its End of Life, and is no longer
receiving security updates.  To protect the integrity of this system, it’s
critical that you enable Extended Security Maintenance updates:
 * https://www.ubuntu.com/esm

Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
Last login: Sat Sep 15 23:40:43 2018 from 10.0.2.2

vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo apt-get install scrapy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sudo apt-cache search scrapy
```

to find out the package name. On new Ubuntu systems the package name is `python-scrapy`, so:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always install Scrapy with `pip`:

```
pip install scrapy
```